# Socrata SODA End Point object return limit

Tags: json, rest, soql, socrata

I want to get a Medicare.gov dataset via the SODA API End Point.

Does [SoQL](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries.html) support a 'not equal to' operator (`<>` or `!=`) ?

My URI string returns results...

https://data.medicare.gov/resource/77hc-ibv8.json?$select=hospital_name,state,measure_name,score&measure_name=%27Catheter-Associated%20Urinary%20Tract%20Infections%20(CAUTI)%27

I want to filter with something like `$where=score <> 'Not Available'`.

How might I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoQL DOES support `!=` if your encoding is correct.

This seems to be missing from the Socrata documentation.

Comment: Yep, Colin is correct. The `!=` operator does work for "not equal". It's in the documentation for the operators for the `Text` datatype: http://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/text.html